# How can a pure binary file be disassembled?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

This code, for example :

```
    global _start
    section .text

    mov ecx, 1
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

    section .data

    dd 0xCAFECAFE
    dd 0xDEADBEEF

    section .data

    dd 0xDEADCAFE
```

When I generate a pure binary file with nasm -f bin, the file looks like this :

```
66 B9 01 00  00 00 66 B8  01 00 00 00  CD 80 00 00  FE CA FE CA  EF BE AD DE  FE CA AD DE
```

Unlike ELF files, there is no indication about where is the .text, .data and .bss section. Despite this, is there any way to disassemble this kind of files ? The problem is that the disassembler could confuse data with instructions.

Comment: Yes, that is a very real problem. It will be your job to guess which parts to disassemble. Luckily, data rarely makes sense as instructions.

Comment: can't answer because my knowledge is outdated but in the olden days we had to make multiple passes to "guess" what's what. I'm pretty sure that it's still available and probably even improved.

Comment: variable length instruction sets like x86, which I assume this is, make this difficult at best.  There is no complete fool proof solution, usually the binary still has some context that gives you a starting point is it a rom that boots the x86, is it a linux binary (probably an elf then and you dont have a problem, etc). so if in this form (one that you didnt create but one you found) it is probably something that boots the cpu so you know the entry point, but you can only get so far with that. because operating systems need headers to know what the file is and where to load, etc.

Comment: being a simple example of an incomplete program this of course is expected to be a complete failure to reverse engineer.  But larger, real, in particular compiled programs you have a bit of a chance to reverse engineer or disassemble at least a percentage of it, unless someone hand tuned the data to disrupt disassembly.